# How can I save iframe content in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have a settings page in my admin panel where the user can paste their Google map iframe code (embed code). The setting options are saved in the database and displayed in various places on the front-end.

My problem is that when I save the settings, the map embed code isn't saved to the database. I guess it's a sanitization problem.

Here is my code from my controller:

```
public function updateGeneral(Request $request) {
        $id = $request->id;

        $data = array();
        $data['site_title'] = $request->site_title;
        $data['meta_description'] = $request->meta_description;
        $data['site_lang'] = $request->site_lang;
        $data['company_name'] = $request->company_name;
        $data['address'] = $request->address;
        $data['phone'] = $request->phone;
        $data['map'] = $request->map;
        $data['email'] = $request->email;
        $data['facebook'] = $request->facebook;
        $data['twitter'] = $request->twitter;
        $data['youtube'] = $request->youtube;
        $data['insta'] = $request->insta;

        // Update table with new data
        DB::table('settings')->where('id', $id)->update($data);
        return redirect(route('admin.settings'))->with('successMsg', 'Settings have been updated successfully!');
    }
```

So how can I make sure that the data is saved for:

```
$data['map'] = $request->map;
```

Comment: Please can you show your table migration/schema and the output of `dd($data);` before the `DB...update()` line.

Comment: here it is : `$table->string('map')->nullable();`

Comment: output of dd `array:12 [▼
  "site_title" => "GenesysLMS"
  "meta_description" => "Genesys meta description"
  "site_lang" => null
  "company_name" => null
  "address" => "4420 Fairway Drive, Vacaville, CA 95688"
  "phone" => "555-555-555"
  "map" => null
  "email" => "info@yoursite.com"
  "facebook" => null
  "twitter" => null
  "youtube" => null
  "insta" => null
]`

Comment: Going off the data in your last comment the `map` value is `null`. This would suggest that isn't not getting submitted. Please can you edit your question and show your form for the settings page.

Comment: by default all other fields are NULL, but when I update the form all other fields get updated except the map. I just realized that this field was added directly in phpmyadmin not via migration. Can that cause the issue?

Comment: If the field exists in the database then that shouldn't be the issue. The `$data` array you've outputted in your earlier comment showed  `"map" => null` which is why the field in the database is `null` i.e. the value is not getting submitted.

Comment: Since the issue was just a typo please can you delete the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, just realized there was a typoo in form name field. But I also had to change the db field from varchar to text.